# Failed to get MaxValue from data

Tags: c#, arrays

well, maybe this is a simple question for you, but for a newbie like me it's kinda confusing

okey, I try to get a maximum value from an array, here's my code

```
int sample = input.GetLength(0);
double maxValue = double.MinValue;  

for (int i = 0; i < sample; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    if (value[i][j] > maxValue)
                        maxValue = value[i][j];
                }
            }
    SetText(textBox1, maxValue.ToString());
```

And here is my number

```
10192 20351 30473 40499 50449 60234 
10192 20207 30206 40203 50205 60226 
10192 20252 30312 40376 50334 60252
```

but when I showed it, the number is wrong. or weird for me. 
instead like 60234

it showed 1.0612312312E-308 something like that.

is it my code wrong or there's something missing?

thanks for any help anyway.

EDIT

VALUE is

the number with jagged array indexing

so it's based on row and column like

value[0][0] for 1st row and 1st column so on.

what I want to do is search in all indexed array and show the maximumvalue.

Comment: What is "value" in your code?

Comment: thanks, i add some explanation above, hope it's helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should do this:

```
double maxValue = double.MinValue;
for (int i = 0; i < value.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < value.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        if (value[i][j] > maxValue)
        maxValue = value[i][j];
    }
}
SetText(textBox1, maxValue.ToString());
```

Comment: i declared it, with double maxValue = double.MaxValue; so your code wont work anymore since maxValue is already declared.

Comment: @Reza - if you've set it to `double.MaxValue` then nothing can be greater than that so your test will always fail.

Comment: But can I ask one question? it's says, MinValue represent the smallest possible value. It is smallest right? how come it is search for the biggest?

Comment: @Reza: you search the highest number; so you start setting it to the lowest, so when you compare the first time, it will be set to actual number and so on...